# How to do composite parallelism (similar to MPI+OpenMP) with Dask

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed

I'm just learning Dask and understand it's application to embarassingly-parallel tasks. I have a function that reads data from a single file and performs a long-running computation on that data. I sped up that computation by parallelizing with joblib.

I now want to scale this up to multiple distributed machines with Dask. I'd like to request some number of nodes and have each machine/node process one file from a pool of files and return the result. I want the processing of each file to utilize some kind of local on-node parallelism.

If this was MPI+OpenMP, I would have one rank on each machine and the number of physical cores as OpenMP threads per rank. With Dask, I only see how to create a giant pool of workers that will share the processing of each file or all files. I want composite parallelism (one file per node, ncore processes per node helping process each file)

I tried calling a joblib function with dask, but it did not utilize all of the cores on each machine. I also don't see how to pin submitted tasks via client.submit to a certain machine.

```
import joblib
import itertools
import numpy as np


#world's stupidest function as a simple illustrative example, matrix is read in from a file and this function is called on many different pairs in conjunction with the matrix to create a very expensive computation. parallelization over the list of pairs is trivial 
def example(matrix, pair):
    for i in range(100000): #takes almost no time
    #for i in range(10000000): #takes a long time
        x=np.exp(100)
    return pair[0]+pair[1]+pair[2]

def my_parallel_example(matrix, pairs, num_jobs):
    results= joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=num_jobs, verbose=10)(joblib.delayed(example)(matrix, pair) for pair in pairs) 
    return results


from dask_jobqueue import SGECluster

cores_per_node=24

cluster = SGECluster(
    cores=1,
    dashboard_address=':0',
    job_extra=['-pe {} {}'.format(parallel_environment, cores_per_node), '-j y', '-o /dev/null'],
    local_directory='$TMPDIR',
    memory=100 GiB,
    processes=cores_per_node,
    project=project_name,
    walltime='00:30:00'
)

#just requesting one 24-core machine
requested_cores=24
cluster.scale(requested_nodes)
client.wait_for_workers(requested_nodes)

matrix=None
possibilities=[1, 2, 3]
pairs = list(itertools.product(possibilities, possibilities, possibilities))
num_jobs=10
c=client.submit(my_parallel_bfs, matrix, pairs, num_jobs)
```

Eventually I want something like this, but I can't figure out the syntax:

```
matrices=[mat1, mat2, ...] #each matrix read from a seperate file and added to a pool of 'big' jobs to be tackled by a node
results=[]
for matrix in matrices: 
    c=client.submit(my_parallel_bfs, matrix, pairs, num_jobs) #each job is submitted to a node that then uses several cores/processes to compute the result corresponding to each file. 
    results.append(c.result() )
```

Everything I'm seeing online seems to use distributed dask for embarassingly parallel jobs and I don't see an example of my application of nesting one big computation per node and using ncore subprocesses on each big computation.

I'd expect the above code to utilize 10 cores as effectively as it did when I ran it directly without dask, but submitting it via client.submit() seems to only use one core. And I can't figure out how to scale to multiple machines in such a way that each machine works without communication on one matrix from a pool of matrices.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what operations you are trying to perform on your matrices? The best solution might depend on that..,

Comment: It's actually a depth first search on pairs of indicies in the matrix. Shortest path that doesn't cross over an element of "0" in the array. I parallelized locally with joblib by creating a pool of pairs to perform a dfs between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after wrestling with this for a long time, and finding a lot of issues online about mixing joblib/Dask (e.g. https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/875), I came up with a good-enough workaround and can post a partial answer.

Ideally, I wanted to submit independent "parent" tasks with dask to separate clients (machines) and have each task call a compute-intensive function parallelized with joblib (using one joblib worker per core). Ultimately, I never saw good performance with this even after wrestling with a variety of options (threads vs processes in joblib, number of processes per machine, etc). Having dask call joblib killed my parallelism, perhaps there's some locking mechanism under the hood.

Instead, I rewrote the program to use Dask entirely (one Dask worker per core instead of one worker per machine) and got rid of joblib.

```
cores_per_node=24

cluster = SGECluster(
    cores=cores_per_node,
    dashboard_address=':0',
    job_extra=['-pe {} {}'.format(parallel_environment, cores_per_node), '-j y', '-o /dev/null'],
    local_directory='$TMPDIR',
    memory=100 GiB,
    processes=cores_per_node,
    project=project_name,
    walltime='00:30:00'
)

requested_nodes=2
total_workers=cores_per_node*requested_nodes


cluster.scale(total_workers)
client.wait_for_workers(total_workers)
```

At this point I've requested 2 24-core machines and Dask has 48 workers, so one worker per core.

```
#I was not able to distribute one "file" of work to a machine, but I was able to have multiple machines process one file. 
info=dict #initialize empty dictionary
for file in list_of_files:
    matrix=np.load(file)
    remote_matrix=client.scatter(matrix) #necessary to prevent any dask warnings and seemed to improve performance by reducing communication. each worker 
    futures = []
    for pair in pairs:
        #now each pair is a dask job, previously this was sent as jobs to joblib
        futures.append(client.submit(example, remote_matrix, pair, workers=first_host))
    tmp_result=client.gather(futures) #blocks until all jobs completed
    info[file]=tmp_result #store the results for one file
```

This workaround was only a reasonable choice because of the nature of this particular problem. It was embarassingly parallel and didn't *truly* need two levels of parallelism but could instead have multiple machines process one file at a time. I still am not sure how I would handle a task where I truly needed one "parent" worker per machine that launches subprocesses to respective cores (besides switching to C/Fortran/C++ and using MPI/OMP).

Even using purely Dask, I don't see a way to create a parent/child relationship without some hack (e.g. creating a list of clients instead of using scale_up) that gives me control over the physical placement of tasks/subtasks across multiple machines.